# Rails possible function arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm quite new to Rails and want to improve my workflow. I'd like to know where I can look up possible function parameters for general rails functions. E.g:

I want to use the `render` function. What arguments can I pass it?

In order to answer this question I went to [api.rubyonrails.org](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Rendering.html#method-i-render). But this only tells me the function signature:

`render(*args, &block)`

and I don't now more than before.

To get more information I read through the Ruby on Rails Guide about Layouts and Rendering (which is great). But even if I found what I was looking for it's not an acceptable way to just quickly look up possible options. I'm searching for something more concise.

How would I know that I can pass in things like `:partial` or `:layout` to the function?

Looking through the actual source code is another option. But that's also not very handy.

This `render` function is just an example. This occurred to me in several places where I wanted to use a function and couldn't find good documentation of what it is actually capable of doing.

Comment: `render` was an interesting choice since it has different contexts for ActionView and ActionController but `api.rubyonrails.org` is a great resource but  apidoc can also help [`ActionController::Base#render`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render)  [`ActionView::Base#render`](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActionView/Base/render)

Comment: Wow apidoc is pretty much what I was searching for. How could I miss that site... thanks for the links! No I have to configure Dash to link to this resource ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the partial name that you want to render as argument like as follows :

```
<%= render :partial => 'partial_name' %>
```

OR you can pass params like as follows :

```
<%= render :partial => 'users', :collection => @users, :locals => {:size => 30} %>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But my question is rather how would I know that I can pass in the `:partial`, `:collection` and `:locals` symbols in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

We can use Ruby's reflection features to get a list of parameters (expected arguments) of a method:

```
AbstractController::Rendering.instance_method(:render).parameters
# Output: [[:rest, :args], [:block, :block]]
```

The output consists of pairs of symbols. In each pair, the first symbol tells us the type of the parameter (required, optional, rest, block) and the second reveals the name of the parameter.

As for the types of parameters:

- :req is a required parameter
- :rest are variable arguments
- :opt is an optional parameter
- :block is a block parameter

More information about parameter types is available in [this post at the Zen Ruby blog](http://www.zenruby.info/2016/05/methods-in-ruby.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm rather interested in how I could know that I can pass in things like `:partial` or `:layout` to the `render` function?

Answer (score 0):

to render a partial, you can pass

```
<%= render :partial => 'client', :collection => @users, :as => :client, :locals => {:optional => true} %>
```

where:

`:partial` 
you can pass the name or route to the partial, like "user" or "folder/user"

`:collection`
for example if you have a list of users in @user, then with this parameter, this partial will be repeated as many users are in the collection.

`:as` 
if you pass a collection, automagically will user "user" as the local variable if the model is User, but if you need another local variable for that partial like client in the example, you pass that parameter with  a name for every piece of the collection. so you can say client.name instead of user.name

`:locals`
if you want to pass a local variable to the partial, like you  have a validation inside the partial that says `if optional` then you pass the value in this way, as you see that is in `{}` you can pass more than one with using commas.